# MockMvc fails when request body is empty for Put and Post requests

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mockmvc

I'm pretty new to unit testing with Spring and can't figure out why I can't MockMvc doesn't work with post when the request body is empty. The error I'm getting: `java.lang.AssertionError:Response status expected:<200> but was <404>`. I've gotten the get endpoint to work correctly so I think the rest controller is wired correctly. I'm just wondering how to write a unit test when a POST or PUT request lacks a body, but has params. I've tried different variations of the below such as chaining `.contentType(MediaType.ALL).content("")`, but I always get the same error.

UnitTest.java

```
@Test
public void shouldCreateSomething() throws Exception{
    mockMvc.perform(post(somethingUri).param(idParameter, fieldParameter))
    .andExpect(status().is(200));
}
```

RestAPI.java

```
@Operation(summary = "Updates something", responses = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Something was updated"),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "406", description = "Something was invalid") })
@PutMapping(value = somethingUri)
public void updateSomething(
        @Parameter(description = "Something's id", required = true) @RequestParam String id,
        @Parameter(description = "Something's name to be updated", required = true) @RequestParam String name)
{
        System.out.println("please work");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There ended up being 2 problems with my code.

The 404 error was probably caused by an incorrect URI.

Then the ensuing 400 error was caused by my malformed `param`. It should be:

```
@Test
public void shouldCreateSomething() throws Exception{
    mockMvc.perform(post(somethingUri)
    .param(idPropName, idParameter)
    .param(fieldPropName,fieldParameter))
    .andExpect(status().is(200));
}
```

So nothing to do with empty body at all